# Singleton service is undefined inside interceptor

Tags: angular

I'm trying to inject an `AuthenticationService` into an interceptor service, but when doing so the `AuthenticationService` is undefined;

```
core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'accessToken' of undefined
```

If I add the service as a provider inside `app.module.ts`, then it works fine, but as the `AuthenticationService` is a singleton, it forces it to be constructed multiple times which causes other issues.

Here's part of the `AuthenticationService`;

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
  }
}
```

This is part of my interceptor;

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    return this.authenticationService.accessToken.pipe(take(1), exhaustMap(authentication => {
      let headers = new HttpHeaders();

      if (authentication) {
        headers = headers.append('Authorization','Bearer ' + authentication.accessToken);
      }

      const modifiedReq = req.clone({
        headers: headers
      });
      return next.handle(modifiedReq);
    }));
  }

}
```

And finally, the `app.module.ts` file;

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent

  ],
    imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      RouterModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      DeviceDetectorModule,
      LoginModule,
      SignupModule,
      SharedModule,
      CommunityModule,
      AccountModule
    ],
  exports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    SignupService,
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptorService, multi: true}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

How can I make the `AuthenticationService` not be `undefined` inside the interceptor?

Comment: Which module `AuthenticationService` belongs to? Do you have it in the providers section in that module?

Comment: It is not declared in any modules. I did try declaring it in the root module, but then the service is constructed every time it is needed rather than just once.

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, according to [the Angular documentation on class providers with dependencies](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#class-providers-with-dependencies), you need to provide the `AuthenticationService` in addition to the other providers you have listed in the parent module:

```js
providers: [
  AuthenticationService,
  SignupService,
  {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptorService, multi: true}
]
```

You mention issues with the `AuthenticationService` functioning as a singleton when you do this. Note that there are [two ways to define a singleton according to the Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#providing-a-singleton-service):

1. Set the providedIn property of the @Injectable() to "root".
2. Include the service in the AppModule or in a module that is only imported by the AppModule.

Since the interceptor only works when you explicitly list the provider in the `AppModule`, you should do that and remove the `providedIn` property from the @Injectable annotation:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Angular from v8 to v10 seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: Makes sense; it seemed like an Angular bug that how you provided the service, which was legal, documented, and the 'preferred' way of doing it, didn't work in that context. Glad you got it resolved!